# Find standard matrices for linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Find standard matrices for the following linear transformations

(1) $ T (\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix}  2 \\ 2 \\2 \end{pmatrix}$ , $ \quad $ $ T (\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix}  1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$, $ \quad $ $ T (\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix}  0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ , $ \quad $ $ \quad $$ M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & -2  \end{pmatrix}. $

$ \quad $ Then,  $ T (\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix}  2 &  1 & 0 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} M^{-1}  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} $  ?

(2) $ \quad $ Let $ S_1 = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3   \end{pmatrix}. $ be the standard matrix for linear transformation S.
Let $ T_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2  \\ 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}. $ be the
standard matrix for linear transformation T.

$\quad $ Standard matrix for linear transformation S 0 T = $ S_1T_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 9 \\ 2 & 7   \end{pmatrix}$ ?

I am not sure if the standard matrices are correct. Is there an easier way to check if the standard matrices are correct without finding $ M^{-1} $ in (1)? Thank you.

Comment: Looks correct to me...